# undefined method `sub_category_id' for Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to filter result based on `category_id` and `sub_category_id`.

The line of code is as follows:

```
@wanted_equipments = WantedEquipment.all.filter(params.slice(:category_id)).order("created_at desc").page(params[:page]).per(per_page_items)
```

This line is filtering perfectly based on `category_id` but once I include `sub_category_id` too as follows:

```
@wanted_equipments = WantedEquipment.all.filter(params.slice(:category_id, :sub_category_id)).order("created_at desc").page(params[:page]).per(per_page_items)
```

This is giving me error saying:

```
undefined method `sub_category_id' for #<WantedEquipment::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fb294732870>
```

I debugged it with `Model.where` method passing the same `category_id` and `sub_category_id`. There it gave me the result based on category id and sub category id i passed. The debug code was as follows:

```
x = params[:category_id]
y = params[:sub_category_id]
if x.present? && y.present?
    @wanted_equipments = WantedEquipment.where(category_id: "#{x}", sub_category_id: "#{y}")
end
```

But I  am getting error in this line when I pass the same sub_category_id as in the debug code:

```
@wanted_equipments = WantedEquipment.all.filter(params.slice(:category_id, :sub_category_id)).order("created_at desc").page(params[:page]).per(per_page_items)
```

The filter method in concerns:

```
module Filterable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def filter(filtering_params)
      results = self.where(nil)
      filtering_params.each do |key, value|
        results = results.public_send(key, value) if value.present?
      end
      results
    end
  end
end
```

Please comment if more information is needed.

Comment: What's happening in this `filter` method?

Comment: There is no `filter` method defined explicitly.  That `Model.all.filter` is triggered when when user used to select a category and filter the result based on the category_id. Now I added `sub_category_id` too. Now its breaking.

Comment: That's what I mean, then the error could be in the `filter` method.

Comment: I am working on enhancing earlier developer's code. I thought `filter` is an activerecord method. I looked for if any `filter` method is defined.  I found one module. I am adding it to the question please check it let me know, if that's the one you meant @Iceman

Comment: Could you also post the code for the `WantedEquipment` class

Comment: It does not make sense to run the filter on WantedEquipment.all . All makes a db query to fetch all your records (it is not a scope)

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense? If you `Model.all.where(id: 1)` it will only fetch record with `id=1`

Comment: What's the point of `filter`? Couldn't you just use ActiveRecord's `where` instead?

Comment: I was just trying to retain the earlier developer code doing minimum changes. Trying to keep it optimal. But it started to take more time than I expected. So I went ahead and used `Model.where`.